# É possível passar um valor para um Enum na sua chamada?

Tags: java, enums

Eu criei em Java um `enum` para unidades de medida de massa e preciso que o usuário passe um valor ao utilizá-lo. Por exemplo:

```
enum Weight {
    KILOGRAMS, POUNDS;

    private float value;

    Weight(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weight meuValorParaPeso = Weight.POUNDS(3400); // O peso é de 3400 libras
    }
}
```

Eu sei que em Java, construtores de `enum` só podem ser chamados dentro da própria `enum` e apenas uma vez, na declaração de suas constantes. Uma solução seria criar um método `setValue` para definir o valor. Mas eu gostaria de saber se há alguma outra forma de fazer isso. De preferência, uma forma que seja em uma única linha, como se fosse um construtor.

Minha intenção com isso é passar o valor para certos métodos, identificando em qual unidade de medida o valor está. Por esse motivo, eu não quero criar uma classe ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Só pra ser pedante mesmo, a unidade de peso não é quilograma e nem libra, mas sim alguma unidade de força, como newton. Quilograma e libra são unidades de massa. :D

Comment: Está usando `enum` da forma errada. Só existe uma única instância de cada um na JVM, portanto mudar o valor de `meuValorParaPeso` afetaria todas as variáveis cujo valor é um `POUNDS`. Não tem como fugir de criar uma classe (provavelmente com 2 campos: o valor e a unidade de medida - aliás, ter um `enum` para a unidade medida faria mais sentido)

Comment: @LuizFelipe tinha esquecido isso kkkkk Já editei.

Comment: Me parece mais um erro conceitual, mas Java não tem ADTs, portanto isso não é possível de fazer, pelo menos de forma correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Você está usando `enum` da forma errada. Crie uma classe e pronto.

## Resposta longa

Não dá para usar `enum` da maneira que você pretende, e há vários motivos para isso.

Primeiramente, quando você faz isso:

```
enum Weight {
    KILOGRAMS, POUNDS;
}
```

A JVM cria apenas uma instância de cada um dos valores (ou seja, na JVM existe apenas uma única instância de `KILOGRAMS`, e uma única instância de `POUNDS`, ambos [criados como variáveis `final static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356970)). Não tem como você criar outras instâncias (não dá para ter outros `KILOGRAMS`, nem outros `POUNDS`). A própria [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) diz o seguinte:

> *An enum class has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum class.*

Ou seja, as únicas instâncias existentes de um `enum` são aquelas definidas pelas suas constantes (no caso acima, são `KILOGRAMS` e `POUNDS`). Qualquer tentativa de criar novas instâncias explicitamente (como `new Weight()`, `new POUNDS()`, etc) dará erro de compilação. Você não consegue criar novas instâncias de um `enum`, além daquelas que já foram declaradas.

> Vale lembrar que [o construtor de um `enum` só pode ser privado ou *package private*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (o *default* quando não há nenhum modificador de acesso).

---

Ou seja, a sua ideia de usar um *setter* para o valor não vai funcionar da maneira esperada. Se fizermos assim:

```
enum Weight {
    // tenho que passar os valores para o construtor aqui, senão não compila
    KILOGRAMS(10), POUNDS(20);

    private float value;
    Weight(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(float value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Repare que precisei passar o valor já na declaração de `KILOGRAMS` e `POUNDS`, senão o código nem compila. Ou seja, quando cada uma das constantes do `enum` for inicializada, já serão criadas com o respectivo valor.

Mas como só existe uma instância de cada, então a sua ideia de usar o *setter* não vai funcionar da forma esperada. Por exemplo:

```
Weight peso = Weight.KILOGRAMS;
System.out.println("Peso:" + peso.getValue()); // 10.0

Weight outro = Weight.KILOGRAMS;
outro.setValue(5000); // mudar o valor do outro peso
System.out.println("Outro peso:" + outro.getValue()); // 5000.0
System.out.println("Peso original:" + peso.getValue()); // 5000.0
```

Repare que ao mudar o valor de `outro`, o valor de `peso` também foi alterado. Isso porque na verdade só existe uma instância de `KILOGRAMS`, então tanto `peso` quanto `outro` apontam para a mesma instância. Não tem como usar o `enum` para guardar diferentes instâncias, cada uma com seu valor (ou seja, não tem como ter mais de um `KILOGRAMS`, cada um com um `value` diferente).

E como também não dá para criar novas instâncias (nada de `new KILOGRAMS(outroValor)`), então realmente não tem como fazer o que você quer somente com `enum`.

---

#### Então qual a solução?

Crie uma classe (você disse que não queria<sup>*****</sup>, mas nesse caso não vejo outra opção <sup><sub>*a não ser que mude de linguagem*</sub></sup>), que contém o valor e a unidade de medida. Algo assim:

```
public enum WeightUnit {
    KILOGRAMS, POUNDS;
}

public class Weight {
    private float value;
    private WeightUnit unit;
}

// assim você pode fazer:
Weight w1 = new Weight(50, WeightUnit.POUNDS);
Weight w2 = new Weight(100, WeightUnit.KILOGRAMS);
```

Desta forma fica também mais organizado, já que a primeira opção não me parece muito boa: seu `enum` original é somente para designar a unidade de medida, não o valor, então estava tendo uma mistura de ambos os conceitos no mesmo lugar (isso, e mais as restrições da linguagem, acabou tornando seu objetivo inicial impossível).

---

<sup>***** <sarcasm>Se não quer criar uma classe, então por que está usando Java?</sarcasm> :-)</sup>

Comment: Não é que eu não queria criar uma classe. Eu apenas queria escrever um código pequeno e sem duplicidade como mandam as boas práticas. E até o momento que eu tinha escrito a pergunta, eu pensava que usando classes eu teria que duplicar o código várias vezes, pois na minha cabeça, eu teria que criar uma classe para `Weight`, outra para `Distance`, e por aí vai, todas com as mesmas funcionalidades. Mas aí eu pensei melhor e criei uma classe genérica que resolveu quase todos os problemas. De todo modo, muito obrigado pela resposta :-)

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](/a/400495/112052), muitas vezes a tentativa de "escrever menos" pode acabar piorando as coisas (como vc mesmo percebeu). Eu vejo as "boas práticas" como um guia geral (recomendações), não é algo que deve ser seguido à-risca-cegamente-a-todo-custo-sem-pensar (prefiro ser pragmático, quebrar "regras" quando for necessário). Java é verbosa (uma das críticas a ela; hoje melhorou um pouco, mas ainda não é o ideal), e nesse caso não tem muito o que fazer. E criar 2 classes ou 2 enums para "peso" e "distância" não chega a ser um problema...

Comment: ...pois são 2 conceitos diferentes (embora relacionados, já que ambos são unidades de medida). Claro que a modelagem perfeita também não existe, e depende muito dos requisitos do sistema para saber qual abordagem funcionaria melhor (por isso só dei uma sugestão genérica, pois não sei de todo o contexto, e de qq forma isso foge do escopo da pergunta). Daria pra fazer em uma classe só (`Unit`, com um campo descrevendo o tipo/nome da unidade, por exemplo), mas sem saber os requisitos, não dá pra cravar o que seria "melhor".